# django no such table error with multiple m2m

Tags: django

On a website I am building, users have 1 account with multiple profiles. When the user signs in, it loads all of the profiles associated with that account into a session in order to display info for all the profiles in the view, among other things. I just added the field `bookmarks` to the Profile class. When I sign in, I get an error `no such table: users_profile_bookmarks`, and the line `profile = model_to_dict(profile)` is highlighted in the traceback.

I am using south to manage db migrations, and the migration works fine. I can even `./manage.py shell` and create, read and delete instances of `Profile`, but I get the same error when I try to add a profile to the `bookmarks` field in the shell.

Here are the models:

```
from django.db import models

class Account(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    viewed = models.ManyToManyField('Profile', null=True, blank=True, related_name='viewed_profiles')
    visitors = models.ManyToManyField('Profile', null=True, blank=True, related_name='visitors_profiles')

class Profile(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    field2 = models.IntegerField()
    account = models.ForeignKey('Account', null=True, blank=True)
    links = models.ManyToManyField('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='links')
    bookmarks = models.ManyToManyField('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='bookmarks')
```

Comment: Have you tried to play with the [symmetrical parameter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical)?

Comment: Messed with it. Nothing changed, although thank you for pointing that parameter out, as it does need to be set to False to work as intended.

Comment: looks like i had messed something up with my south migrations.  i ended up deleting the whole database and all previous migrations and started fresh.

Comment: No problem, that was just a wild guess! I don't think I'd be able to help you more though, sorry!